# Columns with mutator lose cssClass styling

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Is there any way to use a cssClass and a mutator at the same time? Or some other way to get the same effect? It seems that when I use a mutator and a cssClass at the same time, the column loses its styling.

```
{title:"col1", field:"col1", mutator:col1Mutator, cssClass:"not-editable", visible:true, download:false},
```